# Should I delete my 0 voted, no answer, low view questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

This question, for example: [ActiveScaffold thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18392769/1454117).

At the time of posting this meta question, the question above has 0 votes, no answers, and 28 views (and it is approximately 1 year old). It's not a particularly good fit for SO either now that I've learned the site better.

Should I delete it? Are there any negative ramifications to that decision?

Comment: Negative ramification - deleted posts count towards question bans.

Comment: Just wait 3 weeks and it will be [deleted automatically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/144883) :)

Comment: FWIW I don't think it's a bad question nor a bad fit.  What you're asking about is clear and presumably isn't something easily found in the documentation.

Comment: do you still need the answer?

Comment: Well, bounty added. Hopefully it draws some interest.

Comment: @SamIam I don't really *need* an answer any more. I'm still curious though. I moved away from that technology do to the thread safety and other issues.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're absolutely welcome; though I know little enough about RoR, so I'll award the bounty to the highest voted answer, or the answer with the best explanation assuming a voting-tie. Obviously this presupposes answers will appear.

Comment: @Schwern I think it's not a great fit due to the length a good answer would need to be (list all the components that aren't threadsafe, discuss why, discuss whether or not it's still threatsafe if you don't use them, etc) and the likelihood a good answer will become stale as soon as a new version is released.

Comment: _and 28 views_ Not anymore :)

Comment: Like the Colbert-Bump, the Meta-Bump is a real thing.  Also like the Colbert-Bump, I'm never sure if I'm being informed or sold down the river.

Comment: Don't delete it. How else are people like me supposed to rack up necromancy badges? :-)

Comment: I also recently faced the same issue as @LeviStanley, this brings very confusion, since the question is no longer productive as the problem was mistake from my end, even the answer was totally on different technology, than what i asked for, deleting seemed reasonable and valid

Comment: Well, it's got a 500 point bonus, 22 upvotes, two "favorite question" stars, and an upvoted answer now. Good advertising!! :-)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion How many question deletes does it take to be question banned? I'm close to being question banned and I obviously do not want that to happen. I delete lots of outdated posts.

Comment: Posting on meta seems to be a good way to fix 0 votes, no answer, and low views :D

Comment: The exact formula of the ban is not published. But you can get out of it by undeleting you posts and making positive contribution such as raising helpful flags, doing reviews, suggested edits and writing answers. @DavidB

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If it were me...

If I was still interested in the answer AND if it's not causing any problems, like generating lots of off-topic comments, I'd just leave it.  I would clean up the post to be a better Stack Overflow fit and possibly put a bounty on it.

If I were not interested in the answer, and I didn't feel it's a good Stack Overflow fit, and that nobody else is likely to be interested... eh... it's not like it's taking up space on a shelf. Maybe someone will come along and answer it.  Maybe moderators will come along and close it. If it was bothering me enough to post on meta about it, I'd delete it.

What I wouldn't do is worry much about how it affects your reputation points. That way madness lies. For example, back when Stack Overflow displayed your accept rate I used to get [bagged on for having a low accept rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960323/why-dont-php-attributes-allow-functions#comment4232860_3960323). Rather than mark as accepted questions which I didn't feel weren't fully answered, or delete them, I reviewed my unaccepted questions, accepted a few I'd missed, but left the rest unaccepted. I sometimes ask difficult or obscure questions.

The reputation system guides your decisions, it should not make them for you. It is flexible enough to allow you to make a few honest mistakes without serious consequences.

Answer (score 10):

The only ramification that there might be is that it counts towards an automatic question block.

However, with the reputation you have and the number of questions and answers you have posted I don't think that will it actually affect you at all.

Comment: Shog said it only counts if you're deleting it closely after posting it or if there are answers.

Answer (score 9):

## Wisdom of the Ancients

[image: All long help threads should have a sticky globally-editable post at the top saying 'DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far ...']

[*All long help threads should have a sticky globally-editable post at the top saying 'DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far ...'*](http://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 2):

From a fairly new user's point of view (1 year) I still find these kind of questions useful as they help me guage whether a similar question is likely to get a response and therefore perhaps not worth writing if it requires a fair bit of effort.

If I still decide to write a question similar (not too similar) to 1 that has little interest at least I won't hold my breath and can even save some time in my explanation (not detail obviously) by referencing the other question. I may even find that by wording my question slightly differently, adding different relevant tags and such that I get more interest, discover the answer and can then help the person with the initial question, and maybe even gain some more rep as a result.

So in my view they're still valid, though perhaps less so to the person who wrote it in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe someone is doing a statistic about all the questions, for whatever purpose. Then I would leave it.