# Is it known that user can recover from "asking ban"?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Some time ago I asked a question about making custom binary file handlers, and it got deleted pretty quick (1 day to be closed, and 10 days to be deleted) and after that every time I have a problem I see an "fun" warning about "asking ban". I've tried to look up how long does this warning last, but no luck finding the answer (it looks like it is indefinite). Having this warning has hindered me in asking questions in general.

What I am curious is next:

In your experience, have you ever witnessed that someone has recovered from this type of warning or ban?

### Conclusion

After a conversation with users in comments, and my last short fused response. I can say next:

**The clean up works! After I've cleaned up first two questions, the warning disappeared! So to all users who had similar problem as mine, the methodology described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th/255584#255584) almost momentarily improved my status.**

*My mistakes:*

> - I didn't know where to find all my deleted posts and therefore I was under false impression I deleted one or two questions (while I had 7 deleted questions). If you were like me and **deleted any question (no mater how verbose it was) if it didn't have any response after 30 days**, please ask moderator to point your questions to you.
> - It takes time to learn tech linguo. As I started coding ,being self thought, often my implementations were rediscovering the wheel, so issues I had were often (and are now) too complex for my vocabulary to process with some ignorance. So my questions were unclear and often jungle of words. If you have similar problems, (don't delete your question, let it plummet in votes), and return every month or so with new eyes and greater experience to revise your own questions. `Votes taketh, can be returneth again`.

*What helped me*

> - I still have every project I tried or done in archive, which helped me understand my own questions (which is ironic now) and after some number of years be able to look up the documentation for the code and be very concise in editing questions that are at fault. So I didn't have to read all my thought salad from the question, I could look up the code, go to the repository with an timedate of the question and see `what the hell I was babbling about`.
> - Formatting and pseudo code in concrete language I was working on at a time to explain more `abstract` elements for the question.
> - Help of good people in this topic. And some nice people who followed every change I had and upvoted it - therefore helping my case a lot.

My experience:

If this happened to you, you can't help yourself. If you try: you will just repeat same mistakes and often skip most important deleted questions (due to not remembering). You need help from the community, that you are (probably) currently angry at. Swallow that anger, and try to think about possibility that you (by extension me) are currently wrong, or misinformed by vocabulary,language barrier ... name your poison.

If you try to ask "how to fix the problem`", by still being angry, you will normally find an equal and opposite response to your action.

**I still have a lots of question I need to rework, and to do so in future. This probably isn't `it` for me. So in order to persuade other members in similar positions to actively seek help and become better contributors in community - I will try to update this questions if anything of social relevance occurs on this topic.**

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th please. You shouldn't try to create a new account to circumvent a possible ban in any case.

Comment: @Machavity it isn't duplicate. The warning clearly points me to the list of actions i can take to prevent that. This is question about best course of action.

Comment: @Danilo Well, do as advised. Overhaul your older questions to improve them, before asking new questions. Especially the ones you deleted. Why do you think this is a _"fun warning"_ BTW? It was serious, and you should notice that.

Comment: I've only deleted 1 question since it was necessary for `delete your own question with 3 votes or higher` badge. On other questions i was "trusted" and since that question i am not. And i have questions that propose ( show in code ) an dumb way to do something that was corrected in answer. I don't know what to edit there. I can edit last 2 attempts, but i don't see how that will help since warning wasn't from the future.

Comment: probably best not to delete a question just to get a badge. And as we don't take such badges away once earned you can always undelete that question now.

Comment: @RobertLongson it was over a year ago... I was naive and stupid. That question is long gone now - I can't do nothing about it.

Comment: @Danilo Uhm, [I did leave a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/388844/2)

Comment: You won't get a ban for one problematic question. You likely have more questions that were downvoted and deleted. A moderator will probably post links to them here. You can then start to edit them.

Comment: @ModusTollens that would be nice. Machavity ... yeah you did in the edit, but not in the comment. If you were to mention it in the comment i could've replaced it or take it down myself.

Comment: And honestly i don't see this question as a duplicate. I did edit this question to make my question clearer. I know `what` i can do to help my case, but i don't know if that course of action ever worked.

Comment: You don't seem to be currently in a question ban, but here are your previously deleted questions that are scored <= 0, which may count towards the warning ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/57163087) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/57103757) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/41780741) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/40608842) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/40562604) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/39130197) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/36805387))

Comment: @danilo I can post an answer that tells you how to fix the questions Samuel listed. It’ll be a few hours though. If this question gets deleted in the meantime I’ll undelete it and reopen to help you out.

Comment: That would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281256/are-there-instances-of-people-recovering-from-a-question-ban-and-going-on-to-be

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317186/578411

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313641/578411

Comment: So basically, yes: It is known that users can recover. Let's see if you can with the help of George.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your [first deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57163087) it was closed as too broad; and looking at the question it is well formed and too broad.
The question itself mixes “best practices” (using phrases like “is it smart to X”) and questions that would have an objective answer.  We aren’t well suited to answering questions about best practices because it boils down to context and opinions, and the random internet user looking for guidance won’t have the necessary context to do anything more than cargo cult with the answer.

Another recommendation I have is to not betray your ignorance; as that unfortunately raises red flags to prospective viewers that you’re looking for opinions.

Underneath all of that, I recommend you boil down the question to one that reflects an actual problem you face. Are you having a hard time adding new classes due to this preprocessor directive? Is the structure of the project causing you pain in some way? If so, focus on that and focus on a singular problem you face. If you have multiple questions, it causes answers to have to be longer, and at some point that puts the question into “too broad” territory (though I would have closed the question as “primarily opinion based instead).

If you edit that question down and focus on a problem you’re facing, flag it and I’ll undelete and reopen it.

For your [second deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57103757), you asked about how to handle serializing and de-serializing a custom structured file. Your question drew close votes when you said something to the effect of “does anyone have any literature to help me with this”, and that drew the close votes.

My recommendation is to edit your question down to its bare essentials. The file format (or something that is representative of it), the struct or class you want to deserialize it into, and your attempt to do so with the problem you have with it. You mentioned really interesting constraints like a 50 byte limit; that’s important. No one is expecting to you to do this, but we are expecting you to give us concrete code to go off of.  Remember: we are here to solve a particular problem: and deserializing a custom format into a struct under 50 bytes is a particular problem that has wide applicability. But your question needs to be particular. The more you try to generalize it the harder it is to put a useful answer that anyone can point to and say “this is the right answer”.

(I’m on mobile so I’m going to hit “answer” and then edit this answer with the other deleted questions. I don’t want my answers to get lost, so bear with me).

Comment: [Are you writing a partial answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388135/this-answer-is-a-stub-a-partial-solution-for-partial-answers-on-meta)?  ;)

Comment: This answer covers the deleted questions I see at this point; i can address any other closed ones later.

Comment: you might want to address the old comments under the questions that were edited as well, either by giving advice here to flag them for no longer needed or use your own mod powers to clean-up. Some question edits obsoleted a bunch of the existing comments.

Comment: I edited most of other questions that Samuel listed. And so far these two are last remaining. So this isn't partial answer. I will implement changes now.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker the issue of second question is that i had to invent some maths and derive implementations ( such as conversion from ternary + to binary logic ) for my genetic mixed neural and genetic AI ( first layer is genetic, next is intertwined of genetic and neural network ) and most of structures i am serialising are based upon that and there is `up to 50 bytes` serialisation comes from. So i can give links to github as an code implementations, or use pseudo code that would need to show 30 + paper on logic dimensions, plus 12 c++ files per iteration ( there are 4 ). It will be to broad.

Comment: I would really need your help in using right words and minimized code for second question. I don't think i can do it alone without trying to explain how i wanted to implement dna sequence with all its triplets, and dna remapping to rna ,trna,mrna and etc.

Comment: I edited those two answers, to the best of my knowledge. One of mod flags was rejected. Still awaiting for any input from you.

Comment: Also since the time i did write an second question i've fixed my problem. So if that question is deemed ok, i can place an answer to it.

Answer (score -10):

Around in 2014 I was once on Q-ban. Some weeks later I could again ask questions. There was no explanation, it simply disappeared exactly so mysteriously as it arrived. I have no record from it, I have only cloudy remembers that it ever existed.

However, that Q-ban formed a lot my opinion about the community and its voting morale.

You can circumvent the Q-ban if you really want. The problem is the SO

*does not worth its price as the platform where you can get answers to your questions*.

You can get back if you really want. They might catch you or not. The problem is that asking any questions is so hard, the community is so toxic, and the treatment of the questions is so hostile, that it is easier to find the answers for yourself. It does not matter if you are doing it with your first account or with secondary ones.

Working on the SO - and, with the SO - can have a nice motivation that you want to make the community or the world a little bit better. You might have a motivation of the cleanup - this Augeas' stable should be cleaned up, on the psychological/moral level as in the content.

But if your motivation is that you ask here questions, and you will get answers, you are on the bad track.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand "this Augeas' stable should be cleaned up" part? Is that some sort of metaphor or something? Could you explain it better?  
  
To me it is interesting that user with reps over 1K has this experience and opinion. Badges and reputation often ask for some sort of effort or work to be put in community. And for someone to deem SO as toxic and hostile with some work prior put in it shows that this doesn't happen to new users only. It can happen to everyone.  
  
I personally would like to give it another shot, and to try to show the change i wish to see. I can only try

Comment: And i think it is also important to mention ( or show ) is that, you did manage ( somehow by some unknown magics ) to rise above Question ban, and therefore it isn't end of the world.

Comment: I am trying to fix it. Augeas' stabile, that can you find by Google. "I" is always capital letter on English. The MSO is very hostile, far more hostile than the SO, and it does not represent the SO community.

Comment: I don't know the rules at the time, and only few know the rules today. I think the SO first tries to hide, that there is far lesser answerers as questions, so they make asking questions hard. Then, in the lack of questions, they expel answerers (for example, by essentially criminalizing rep collection, instead of encouraging it). Then they whine that the stats won't increase since 2015. No! They don't whine! They are phylosophing about, what is why offtopic, and they consider the stats an insult!

Comment: Hi. I'm your friendly neighborhood fact checker. Rep collection has never been criminalized, and has been encouraged. All askers and answerers are presented with the information they need to write good questions and answers, and through that earn rep. Whether people decide to follow that or not, however, is not SE's problem - that's the individual's problem. The reason stats have gone down is because there's only so many questions to ask. The first few years, there were practically no duplicates because they didn't exist. Also, the standards were different and have since changed.

Comment: The stats have never been considered an insult. If SE attempted to chase away new users, the community would eventually wither and die (because no users in - the inevitable users out will eventually leave no users if there's no one new joining). There's in fact new people joining daily, and some of them manage to get familiar with the insanely large definitions of what's OK, and what isn't. Many people don't, either because they just came here to ask a question and nothing more, or because they for some other reason just don't come back. Getting used to all the guidelines is a job of its own.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're confusing a desire to stay and gain rep with something everyone has to do. No one is required to stay and collect relatively useless internet points after posting a single question, and no one is required to moderate the site either. Those who do, do so because they want for whatever personal reasons they have, whether that's showing off to potential employers, or just because they want to be a part of the community. You're making the question quality stats into a hyperbole. Fallign quality != criminalizing rep collection.

Comment: @Danilo My motivation is the cleanup. Sometimes, rarely, I really can find answers here, mostly not by asking a question, but finding the questions of others. Doing that, I also make a signifikant voting/edit/flagging activity. But, the probability, that I can't find an answer to my problem here, AND I can find one by creating and taking care of a new question, is very low. I am also trying to represent the opinion of the SE users who aren't already among us.